# Would a query run in a try statement that failed if it was before the error occured?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

Lets say I have the following example (Pseudo Code Example)

```
try{
     INSERT SQL to DB 1
     INSERT SQL to DB 2
     --FAILURE OCCURS HERE FOR SOME REASON AND IT GOES TO CATCH STATEMENT
     INSERT SQL to DB 3
 }catch(err){
     ERROR MESSAGE  
 }
```

Would The first two query's be run on the DB because they were before the error?

**or**

Would the program know theres an error and not run the code block in the try statement and jump strait to the catch block?

Comment: If you put a transaction around the code then you can roll back everything when an error occurs.

Comment: Yes they would get executed. You need transactions to handle this situation.

Comment: Okay thanks I see what your saying : )

Answer (score 2):

This is how you could handle the situation you describe inside a stored procedure:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY   
   INSERT SQL to DB 1
   INSERT SQL to DB 2
   --FAILURE OCCURS HERE FOR SOME REASON AND IT GOES TO CATCH STATEMENT
   INSERT SQL to DB 3
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH         
   IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;            

   -- Return 0 value to indicate failure of execution
   RETURN 0                             

END CATCH;

-- If transaction is still active then commit it
IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) 
   COMMIT TRANSACTION;

-- Return 1 value to indicate successful execution of INSERT statements
RETURN 1
```

If there is a failure of *any* `INSERT` statement inside the `TRY` block, then *all* of these statements are rolled back. Otherwise, all of the `INSERT` queries are committed to the database.

You could implement similar logic in C#, but it is generally preferable to wrap the whole implementation in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways in programming languages (DB adapters/interfaces) to handle transactions on DB level. If these three queries are not wrapped around some code which essentially opens a transaction and ends it after third statement using a commit, then the above two queries would have already run on the DB and committed individually. 
Judging from your code, there are no transaction open/commit/rollback lines wrapped around the 3 statements which means that the above two statements have already been committed to the database because the DB considers them individual transactions each.
However if you wrap these 3 statements around a transaction open/commit block, and then if any one statement fails, the already executed queries would get rolled back because the code's catch block will let the DB engine know that the transaction was open and not committed but an exception occured therefore rollback the previously executed statements.